# How do I get WPF Databinding to notice changes to properties on the model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model, viewmodel

I've created an WPF MVVM app. The ViewModel has properties I can bind to from the View.  But one of the properties is basically a model for a json document that has many properties which are either int, string or some other model and so on. In my view I have controls that update these properties.  The object updates but no PropertyChanged events fire.

What's a clean way to handle a situation like this?  Do I have to create dozens of property accessors in my ViewModel or is there a better way?

Edit for more detail:

Now using Fody per Andy:

In my VM:

```
public AppModel AppModel { get; set; }
```

In my Models

```
public class AppModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationVersion { get; set; }
}
```

In my View:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding AppModel.ApplicationName, Mode=TwoWay }"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding AppModel.ApplicationVersion, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When I start the app and create a new doc I show null in the textbox and the json view.

[image: New Doc]

Then I update the textboxes (changing selection a could times to be sure it updated)  but nothing fires to call my code to repopulate the JSON text

[image: After entering data]

I click the Save button which has code to serialize the object to JSON and I can see my data does exist in the object.

[image: After clicking Save]

Comment: Do you want the properties to update individually or can the whole thing update if you changes.

Comment: Is using a code generation tool an option? There are several libraries that can autogenerate properties that work with databinding

Comment: You need public properties to notify change. You can use say fody weaver to generate propertychanged msil. But you still want a bunch of properties in a csharp class. https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: @JohnV I just updated a minimalist example.  The actual code repents a complex JSON document object model with many properties and subproperties.  Anytime any of that changes I want to fire an event to refresh the serialized view of the overall object.  This is basically a designer tool for operations folks to be able to see their changes in JSON in real time and help teach what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: @Andy Thank you very much for pointing out Fody.  Very useful but my problem remains.

Comment: I think I phrased the question wrong. I added a             AppModel.PropertyChanged += AppModel_PropertyChanged and now I'm triggering code in my VM whenever something changed.  I hate answering and accepting my own questions so if @Andy wants to turn his Fody comment into an answer with this I'll accept it.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to stay MVVM and not add a bunch of properties (which makes sense,since the JSON schema could change). I would use data templates.

I would build a hierarchical collection of 'PropertyVMs' from the JSON that is bound to the `ItemSource` of a `TreeView`. Then define a `DataTemplate` for the view of a single PropertyVM. That template would display the name of the node and the node content. When the  content of a node changes, that node can propagate that notification back wherever it needs to go so that the underlying JSON gets updated.

This gives you a lot of flexibility. You could even define different data templates for different kinds of properties, like a numeric up down for numbers and a date time picker for `DateTime`.